# WAFL: Write Anywhere File Layout

Tags: operating-system, filesystems

I wonder if anyone knows about WAFL (Write Anywhere File Layout), or a link to the topic of interest (not wikipedia), or a good bibliography online because I am investigating about operating systems, thanks to all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wikipedia page has links to a PDF from Network Appliance on the system as well as the patent link.  If that's not going to satisfy you then you need to be more specific as to what kind of information you want.

Comment: well, I'm looking for most detailed information about: the origin, definition, current use, file's disposition and management of snapshots, the information from wikipedia.org although very successful is not so complete for what I need to investigate. sorry for my english =p

Answer (score 1):

The NetApp website has an [extensive library](http://www.netapp.com/us/library) of papers about WAFL and their file servers.

If you're interested in technical aspects of what WAFL is and how it works, the [technical report](http://media.netapp.com/documents/wp_3002.pdf) linked from the Wikipedia article is a very good starting point.  This article was originally published at the 1994 USENIX Conference, so it's 15 years old.  Some things have changed---and a lot of features have been added---but it still provides a good description of the key innovations in WAFL.

p.s. FWIW, they stopped calling themselves "Network Appliance" a couple years ago and officially changed their name to "NetApp."

Comment: Yes, the technical report is a pretty good source of information about the WAFL.